# Sorted function for tuple in python

Tags: python, string, sorting, tuples

```
p=('99','655','864','654')
e=sorted(p)
```

the result is `['654', '655', '864', '99']`
why is 99 at last? It should be first.

Comment: You are sorting strings, not integers. That means the order is lexicographical

Comment: Just use the `key` parameter to sort as integers: `sorted(p, key=int)` This will pass each item to `int()` before considering it's sorting order.

Comment: p=('99','655','864','654')
p = [int(x) for x in p]
e=sorted(p)
print(e)